# What are the consequences of the sys.sql_dependencies Catalog View Not Being Updated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I have two trivial stored procedures, created like so:

```
create procedure root as
select 1 
go

create procedure dependant as
exec root
go
```

(Where `dependant` depends on `root`).

When I check the `sys.sql_dependencies` table for the second procedure, I see an entry (as i would expect).

If, however, I add the `dependant` procedure first, I get the following warning.

> Cannot add rows to
>   sys.sql_dependencies for the stored
>   procedure because it depends on the
>   missing table 'root'. The stored
>   procedure will still be created;
>   however, it cannot be successfully
>   executed until the table exists.

And, right enough, `exec dependant;` fails.

So, when I add in the `root` procedure, `exec dependant;` works, however, no dependency is recorded on `sys.sql_dependencies`.

My questions are twofold:

1. What are the consequences of this?
2. Everything seems to hang together quite acceptably, so why doesn't SQL add this record retrospectively?

Help, as always is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The consequences are just that when you come to refactor the database it is more difficult to identify affected objects.

You can refresh all dependencies by writing a script to run `sp_refreshsqlmodule` on all database objects.

In SQL Server 2008 such unresolved dependencies are still stored and are accessible through `sys.sql_expression_dependencies` meaning the dependency information is more reliable.

The SQL Server 2008 behaviour is as follows.

After dependant is created but before root exists

```
SELECT     OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id) AS Name, 
           referencing_class_desc, 
           referenced_class_desc, 
           referenced_entity_name, 
           referenced_id, 
           is_caller_dependent, 
           is_ambiguous
FROM         sys.sql_expression_dependencies
```

Returns

```
Name       referenced_entity_name    referenced_id is_caller_dependent is_ambiguous
---------- ------------------------- ------------- ------------------- ------------
dependant  root                      NULL          1                   0
```

In your example code this is also the results of the query following the creation of `root` as the reference to it is not schema qualified and so is caller dependent. However if the definition of your `dependant` procedure is changed to

```
create procedure dependant as
exec dbo.root
```

Then once `dbo.root` is created the following is returned

```
Name       referenced_entity_name    referenced_id is_caller_dependent is_ambiguous
---------- ------------------------- ------------- ------------------- ------------
dependant  root                      2121058592    0                   0
```